# How can I integrate the job news API into my site to access data through the API?

Tags: database

I want to integrate the API of job news to display news of different companies. I need to let my system access the data through the API.

How can I integrate it with my website? Can anyone help me by telling me a way or giving some idea for the integration process?

Comment: Well. It fully depends on how these API's are exposing the data. SOAP, REST, XMLRPC or a simple XML feed?

Answer (score 1):

With [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module you can import data from other sources to your Drupal installation. I would create a new content type for the jobs, and import the data with Feeds module into this newly created content type.

Comment: I am using the feed module and RSS. And I am getting the list of google news. But I want to filter the news result depending on any string. eg, hdfc so I want to see result for HDFC.